# Android Search Results in ListView

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, geocoding

I am trying to figure out how to search for restaurants around me and have the results show up in a ListView. I have found short leads that mentioned using a GeoCoder. I am not sure how to use this, or if this is correct. Basically I want my user to search "McDonalds", and my app gives it the McDonald's around it. Should I use Google Maps Search or is there a better way? Any information is useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google places api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) to search near by places like in your case restaurant around a particular location.

Comment: Do you of any tutorial that I can look up on how to use this API? Im quite confused..

Comment: Read the link I sent you for some time it has everything you need. Bassically you need to create a google places api key. And pass lat, long, radius, type of places you want to search and api key to this api https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json to get list of placesa round you.